# I am using Fullcalendar jquery plugin but unable to use timezone here

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalendar jquery plugin but unable to use timezone here for showing datetime in different timezone. Lets say I will provide a date time in a timezone Asia/Calcutta, Now I want my calendar to show date time in America/Chicago or any other time zone. How am I going to achieve this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with http://momentjs.com/timezone/ moment js. 
if possible you can make an API call to get time from server side.

cheers.

Comment: I will  provide a json data , to populate into the callendar , but i want to know is there any way where  just by passing any time zone parameter will make it show  converted date time into the callendar